# How to add Polygon touch event handler to many polygons in Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm putting many `Polygons` on Google Maps Android v2 from a datasource, i need to detect when a user touches on one of them; how to add an event handler for this?

Am i forced to cycle on every Polygon for hit detection or there is a more performant method?

Thanks

Comment: Because there is no polygon click listener, that's the only way to do it.

Comment: If you use your Overlay as Polygon, you make use of `Item.GestureListeners`, which would help you for config singleTap & LongTap override methods.